# Concatenate SQL rows from CTE/Temp table based on user selected values in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I need help in concatenating multiple rows in SQL to one row, for the key value (EID) and the values selected in the hierarchy tree.
The tree looks like this (its on an RSA Archer based platform).

[image: Hierarchy Tree]

I have a CTE/Temp table (say its : #tmpBH) that looks like the below [It has 2 fields - EID and Fullpath]. This is based on values selected. For eg. if 'a1' is selected then the Eid takes the value from the root (WFC) till 'a1'.

| EID | Fullpath |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | WFC - CSBB : a1 |
| E1 | WFC - CL |
| E2 | WFC - CSBB : a2 |
| E2 | WFC - CL : b2 : c1 |
| E2 | WFC - CL : b1 |
| E3 | WFC - WIM : c2 : d2 |
| E3 | WFC - WIM : c1 |

The output that I am looking for is as below. Basically, a concatenation of all EIDs into a single row from the above table.

| EID | Fullpath |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | WFC - CSBB : a1 - CL |
| E2 | WFC - CSBB : a2 - CL : b2 : c1 - CL : b1 |
| E3 | WFC - WIM : c2 : d2 - WIM : c1 |

Comment: Search around for Microsoft's "graph tables"

Answer (score 0):

You can look for distinct branches in your tree, a query would be like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP
SELECT  'E1' EID,'WFC - CSBB : a1' Fullpath
INTO #TEMP
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E1','WFC - CL'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E2','WFC - CSBB : a2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E2','WFC - CL : b2 : c1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E2','WFC - CL : b1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E3','WFC - WIM : c2 : d2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E3','WFC - WIM : c1'

SELECT DISTINCT  EID,RIGHT(STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT  ' - ' + value
                    FROM #TEMP b
                    CROSS APPLY string_split(Fullpath,'-')
                    WHERE a.EID = b.EID
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') ,LEN(STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT  ' - ' + value
                    FROM #TEMP b
                    CROSS APPLY string_split(Fullpath,'-')
                    WHERE a.EID = b.EID
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')) - 2)
FROM #TEMP a
CROSS APPLY string_split(Fullpath,'-')
```